# How to correctly set the number of rows of a tableview Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview

I was trying to set the number of rows for my table view in my controller using the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.offers.count;
}
```

offers is an NSArray that I have declared and filled in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Fill arrays accordingly
    if ([self.item  isEqualToString:@"Laptops"]){
        self.offers = @[@"MacBook Air", @"MacBook Pro", @"HP"];
        self.prices = @[@800, @1200, @600];
        self.offerNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.offerPrices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        self.offerNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_offers];
        self.offerPrices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_prices];
        
        
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, I get the following error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe4a88af02df0791a
```

I don't know exactly what's wrong in my code, and I never had this error before.
P.S: I used the same method to set up the other table views in the other controllers and none gave this error.

That's the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface OffersTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property NSString *item;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *offerNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *offerPrices;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

That's where I set the value of the item:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
    OffersTableViewController *offers = segue.destinationViewController;
    
    NSString *chosenItem = [[NSString alloc]init];
    
    if (isFiltered){
         chosenItem = filteredArray[indexPath.row];
    }
    else{
         chosenItem = self.itemNames[indexPath.row];
    }
    
    offers.item = chosenItem;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The error is very descriptive and says that `self.item` is an `NSNumber` instance. A number, not a string.

Comment: @vadian in the header file I set it to be an NSString

Comment: @vadian if I comment the numberOfRowsInSection method, the app works fine

Comment: The compiler doesn't lie. Somewhere you assign an `NSNumber` to `item`

Comment: @vadian I added the code where I set up the value of item do you think there's anything wrong there?

Comment: Please note that the filteredArray and itemNames are arrays, the first is a mutable array, the second is a standard NSArray. They both contain NSString elements

Comment: Declare the homogenous arrays always generic e.g. `NSMutableArray<NSString *>` then the compiler will help you to discover a type mismatch.

Comment: @GabrielChammas you said it works fine if you comment numberOfRowsInSection method. How do you conform to tableview's data source protocol, if you comment that out?

Comment: @SanthoshR it turned out that this was not the error. I found out the error and pointed it out in an answer below :)

Comment:  I suspected it. The code in the question was pretty misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some debugging and after commenting out some lines of code and narrowing down my search. I realized that I needed to fix this line of code

```
cell.detailText.text = self.prices[indexPath.row];
```

To :

```
NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$ %@", self.prices[indexPath.row];
cell.detailText.text = detailText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ([self.item  isEqualToString:@"Laptops"])
```

with

```
if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item] isEqualToString:@"Laptops"]])
```